# Javascript changing of text not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following javascript code

```
  ws.onopen = function() 
  {
    ws.send("running?");
  };

   ws.onmessage = function(evt)
  {
    var phrase = evt.data
    console.log(phrase)
    if(phrase == "1")
    {
    console.log(phrase)
    document.getElementById("Button1").text="Pause"; 
    document.getElementById("Label1").text="Running";
    }   

  };

  //fired when an error occurs during communication with websocket
  ws.onerror = function (error)
  {
    document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "Unknown"
    document.getElementById("Button1").disabled = true; 
  };


  function command() 
  {
    var message = document.getElementById("Button1").value;
    ws.send(message);
  }
```

That goes along with the following HTML code

```
<html>
<script src="script_control.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<p>Script status: <label id="Label1"></label></p>
<button id="Button1" onclick="command()">Pause</button>
</html>
```

Each time the value of phrase outputs to console as `"1"` signifying a text number one. However nothing changes on the page like it is supposed to even though the expression evaluates to try, why might this be happening?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `if` line and be happy! If you don't know how, [see this link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: i figured out it is hitting the `if` but not setting the values

Comment: try to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` or `innerText`   instead of `text`

Comment: @dap.tci you are a life save that worked! if you want to make that an answer ill mark it down as accepted

Comment: @dap.tci the innterhtml worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`labels` and `buttons` do not have a `value` attribute, use `textContent`:

```
document.getElementById("Button1").textContent="Pause"; 
document.getElementById("Label1").textContent="Running";
```

Comment: ok so it does go into the if, but still not change in output.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: im sorry i am new to javascript, what is a fiddle?

Comment: it is using websockets so I am unable to do that. do my if statements look correct? it seems to be hitting the last part of every if statement when i step through which seems weird. correction when i put a debug statement in didnt hit the last part of the if statement

Comment: Not sure then... can try clearing your browser cache to make sure the latest script is being loaded

Comment: just did still the same.

Comment: i added the whole javascript code so you can take a look at that